# error reading variable: Could not find the frame base

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, gdb, clion

I am using Clion IDe, with gcc/g++ & gdb for debugger.

In the CMakeList.txt, I have the following compiler options set.

`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -std=c++11 -fopenmp -fPIC -O0 -gdwarf-2 -finline-functions)`

I can view the variable values in main() but not any other classes. It shows the error for all methods called from the main directly or nested :

`<error reading variable: Could not find the frame base for xxxxclass::xxxMethod>`

Any pointer would be helpful.

Comment: Try  -g instead of -gdwarf-2

Answer (score 1):

Several problems I see:

1. Do not limit yourself to dwarf v2 (`-gdwarf-2`) unless your debugger cannot handle newer dwarf revisions.
2. Try, as much as possible, to disable optimizations (`-O0` should correctly disable `-finline-functions` though). But note that newer dwarf revisions better handle and track optimizations.
3. Try, as much as possible, to make your debug informations verbose. The option `-g` takes an optional argument which is `2` by default, but whose maximum value can be `3`. It will then unlock some debugger features like debugging CPP macros.
4. Enable GDB debug information extensions with `-ggdb`.
5. If it's still complaining, you may still have to explicitly use extra gcc's [debugging options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html). But it is usually only required when debugging an optimized program.

So, try again with:
`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -std=c++11 -fopenmp -fPIC -O0 -g3 -ggdb)`